# how to process json data through an .each loop into html table

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am making an ajax get request that displays json data in a html table. I know how to do this with javascript, so I thought I'd try it with jquery.  There is a  problem in my `.each` loop. I am vague on how the arguments `(key, object)` process more than one key value pair in each position and suspect this is where my error lies.

I have tried `JSON.parse`, but that didn't help. I am definitely getting the data as I can display it in an alert box. I suspect that what I'm doing is not industry standard and that there is a more elegant way to reach my objective.

```
$("#button").click(function(){    

                  $.ajax({
                  type: 'get',
                  url: "http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/animals",
                  data: {format: 'json'  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(data){  

                        var i = 0;
                        var table = '<table class="mainTable"><tr><th>item</th><th>image</th><th>description</th></tr>';

                                 $.each(data, function(key, object){ 

                                            table += ('<tr>');
                                            table += ('<td>' + data.Title + '</td>');
                                            table += ('<td><img src="' + data.ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>');
                                            table += ('<td>' + data.Description + '</td>');
                                            table += ('</tr>');

                                           });

                                     table += '</table>'; 

                                    $('#tableContainer').html(table);

                               }

                         });

                        });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And also if you can provide the JSON you're getting.

Comment: the json is coming from http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/animals .  I have no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the right code that you need, just copy and paste, regards!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id = "btnSubmit" type="button" value="Release"/>

<div id="tableContainer">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){           

              $.ajax({
                      dataType: 'json',
                      url:   "http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/animals",
                      type:  'get',

                      success:  function (data) {
                         var i = 0;
                         var table = '<table class="mainTable"><tr><th>item</th><th>image</th><th>description</th></tr>';
                         data = $.parseJSON(data)
                               $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {                                   
                                    table += ('<tr>');
                                    table += ('<td>' + obj.Title + '</td>');
                                    table += ('<td><img src="' + obj.ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>');
                                    table += ('<td>' + obj.Description + '</td>');
                                    table += ('</tr>');
                              });
                         table += '</table>';
                        $("#tableContainer").html(table);

                      },
                      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("some error");
                      }
              });
    }); 
});




</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your response variable 'data' is an array, you're accessing the wrong variable inside each iteration of your each loop:

```
$("#button").click(function(){    

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/animals",
        data: {format: 'json'  },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){  

            var i = 0;
            var table = '<table class="mainTable"><tr><th>item</th><th>image</th><th>description</th></tr>';

            // NOTE!  I changed 'object' to 'value' here
            // NOTE 2!  We added a JSON.parse on the 'data' variable to convert from JSON to JavaScript objects.
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){ 

                // We need to access the value variable in this loop because 'data' is the original array that we were iterating!
                table += ('<tr>');
                table += ('<td>' + value.Title + '</td>');
                table += ('<td><img src="' + value.ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>');
                table += ('<td>' + value.Description + '</td>');
                table += ('</tr>');

            });

            table += '</table>'; 

            $('#tableContainer').html(table);

        }

    });

});
```

See the comments in the above code for the changes.

See the docs on jQuery's .each() iterator [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: Sorry. This did not work.  It does help me understand this better.

Comment: Check the new code.  Your original idea to JSON.parse was correct, but only with the newly changed variables within the .each() loop that I provided.  Give the new code a shot.  In the future, when you are asking for help in parsing responses via AJAX or the like, it's a good idea to post an example of what the response from the API looks like.  In this case, I had to do a request myself to see the result.

Comment: Thank you. I'm here to learn and all tips appreciated. I will as you advise,

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$.each(data, function(key, object){ 

    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>' + data[key].Title + '</td>';
    table += '<td><img src="' + data[key].ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>';
    table += '<td>' + data[key].Description + '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
});
```

Comment: I think you'll need to give more details about what you are getting

Comment: i'm not getting much. When I click the button I get the table header but no data in the table.

Comment: If you `console.log(table)` what is the result?